# SAS : Can _ERROR_ =1 without an error message in log?

Tags: sas, runtime-error

My question is what will be the value of _error_ be after the second iteration of this data step.

```
data test;
input country $8. date mmddyy10.;
cards;
Germany 12/31/2000
france  2/31/2001
;
run;
```

I saw the answer was 1. Is that right? Can the _error_ variable be =1 without putting an error message in log?
I just ran the program and it doesn't give any error message in the log but the value of date is missing.

TIA

Comment: There will be error = 1 with your code. you can stop by doing option error = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the LOG.  You have invalid data in the date field.  Feb cannot have more that 28 or 29 days.  When SAS encounters invalid data it sets _ERROR_=1. _ERROR_ is an automatic variable similar to _N_, _IORC_ etc.

```
645  data test;
646  input country $8. date mmddyy10.;
647  cards;

NOTE: Invalid data for date in line 649 9-18.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
649        france  2/31/2001
country=france date=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 2 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```